# Why 'check_login()' function always return -1 in C?

Tags: c

struct user_info user is global variable and structure array value is written in a seperate function.. Why 'check_login()' function always return -1?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int load_user_info();
int check_login(int id, int password);
int binary_search_id(struct user_info list[], int n, int id);

struct user_info {
    int id_num;
    int password;
};

struct user_info user[2];

int main(void)
{
    int id, password;
    printf("id password : ");
    scanf("%d %d", &id, &password);
    printf("%d", check_login(id, password));
    return 0;
}

int load_user_info()
{
    user[0].id_num = 1; user[0].password = 10;
    user[1].id_num = 2; user[1].password = 20;
    return 0;
}

int check_login(int id, int password) {
    int i = binary_search_id(user, 2, id);
    if (i < 0)
        return -1;
    else if (password == user[i].password)
        return id;
    else if (password != user[i].password)
        return -2;
}

int binary_search_id(struct user_info list[], int n, int id) {
    int low, high, middle;
    low = 0;
    high = n - 1;
    while (low <= high) {
        middle = (low + high) / 2;
        if (id == list[middle].id_num)
            return middle;
        else if (id > list[middle].id_num)
            low = middle + 1;
        else
            high = middle - 1;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

This is minimal reproducible example
Why 'check_login()' function always return -1?
Thank you!

Comment: Please [edit] and show a [mcve]. Maybe your list is unordered in the first place.

Comment: Please post something that can be compiled and executed. Read this very closely: [mcve].

Comment: Function `check_login` returns -1 if `binary_search_id` returns a value <0, so your [mre] needs a `main` function which calls `check_login` with suitable input arguments to reproduce the problem. `check_login` is not necessary.

Comment: In `int i = binary_search_id(user, MEMNUM, id);` is `MEMNUM` correct? ie, is it the effective number of items in the array ... or maybe it's the maximum number of items in the array??? It probably should be `int i = binary_search_id(user, number_of_items, id);`

Comment: Your edit with the "minimal reproducible example" does not call `load_user_info()` and searches through garbage.

Comment: Ah I thought that the main function ended just by calling a 'load_user_info()' function that return 0. My mistake! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Your binary search function looks fine.

Here is your code with an automated test that shows that it works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct user_info {
  int id_num;
  int password;
};

struct user_info user[100];
int nbofusers;

int load_user_info()
{
  user[0].id_num = 10; user[0].password = 1004;
  user[1].id_num = 20; user[1].password = 2004;
  user[2].id_num = 30; user[2].password = 3004;
  user[3].id_num = 40; user[3].password = 4004;
  user[4].id_num = 50; user[4].password = 5004;
  nbofusers = 5;
  return 0;
}
 

int binary_search_id(struct user_info list[], int n, int id) {
  int low, high, middle;
  low = 0;
  high = n - 1;
  while (low <= high) {
    middle = (low + high) / 2;
    if (id == list[middle].id_num)
      return middle;
    else if (id > list[middle].id_num)
      low = middle + 1;
    else
      high = middle - 1;
  }
  return -1;
}


 int main() {
   load_user_info();

   for (int i = 0; i < nbofusers; i++)
   {
     int index = binary_search_id(user, nbofusers, user[i].id_num);

     if (index < 0)
     {
       printf("binary_search_id returned %d for i = %d\n", index, i);
       return 1;
     }

     if (index != i)
     {
       printf("Test failed for i = %d\n", i);
     }
   }
 }
```

Maybe the `user` array has been created wrong, or `MEMNUM` is wrong in your original code. We can't tell because you didn't provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).